# Submitting search form on website to scrape table

Tags: javascript, python, forms

I'm trying to scrape the tables from this website:
http://kepler.sos.ca.gov/

For example, I want the program to select the radio button for Corporation Name and then submit a corporation name like GOOG in the form. I would like to scrape the data that displays as a result. Can I use the requests library for Python to submit the forms on this page, or do I have to use JavaScript? If so, how can I submit the forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use google chrome and and copy a sample request as 'curl' option. Then replace the form variable (Company name) with your input and save it to a file, then use bs4 to scrape the values you require.